# jQuery: How to trigger this line as a function on a button click?

Tags: jquery

I suck at forming the question itself. Any ways, here's what I want to do.

I have this JavaScript at the bottom of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).foundation(); 
    $(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
</script>
```

It loads Foundation framework, then it reloads abide (I need it to do that). So I have two questions actually...

(1) Is it loading foundation twice as well as reloading abide, or is it just loading foundation once and then reloading abide? I'm asking if it's pointless having both lines or if I should just have the second line.

(2) Okay, the real question... How do I call `$(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');` when I click a link? I need this to perform the way it does right now, as well as on certain button clicks.

If anyone is interested in knowing the actual problem: I'm using foundation (obviously), and they have a tabs function, so on one of my pages I have a series of forms in different tabs, now this abide validation function only loads on page load and although it attaches itself to all the forms... it doesn't work "live" as it does on the first form that appears on page load. So I want to trigger the event when clicking on each tab link - I figure that should do it.

I'm sure there are other questions like this one, I'm just not sure what to ask for those to pop up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I don't believe it is loading Foundation twice. It looks to me like you're using that reflow call the way it is meant to happen, although it seems odd that you have to do that right after the first foundation() call.

2) To enact a function on each click of a link you could do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        $(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
    });
});
```

You could apply this to buttons, or specific classes of links or buttons by modifiying the $('a') selector.

This answer assumes jQuery is being used, which I gather it is from your $(document) calls.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer in 9 minutes when it allows me to =)

Comment: No problem Matthew, happy to help!

Comment: As @user3062917 pointed out, you need to put this kind of event-based code in a $(document).ready() function to make sure that the event is attached to every link after the page is built.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_of_my_link').click(function(){
        $(document).foundation('abide', 'reflow');
    });
});
```

for that you need to have something like this:

`<a id="id_of_my_link">...</a>`, replace id_of_my_link with whatever you want

ps: don't forget to include jquery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```